# How to add new Java Oracle license to my application?

Tags: java

Does anybody have some experience how to work with new Oracle licensing?

I can't find any resources from Oracle to understand how to work with this new licensing and how to embed it, for example, in some application.

The only link I could found is [Licensing and Distribution FAQs](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/distribution.xml)

I will be grateful to any help, for any links and any information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Oracle license to install.

When you download the software you agree with the license agreement and that's (normally) all.

For some Oracle products (including Oracle Database) you don't install any license key, activation key, etc. - this is true for the so called "OTN license" that are free for personal use and for products where you pay the license for commercial use.

But you must comply with the license agreement and Oracle may audit your license usage.

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I can't understand - according to price [link](https://www.oracle.com/assets/java-se-subscription-pricelist-5028356.pdf) license for using costs some money (at about 25 USD per month per processor for server side). So,  I have understood that I have to embed something like license file to every server-side application ( I means commercial using of Java)...

Comment: I don't know all the details for Java but I think that you should have your own system to keep track of your Java usage ; there are maybe tools for that on the market (think asset management etc.).